# MarkLogic ODBC for Tableau - Date casting error

Tags: odbc, tableau-api, marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a MarkLogic ODBC server for a tableau connection. I have created the view and is already accessible. However, I am having problems manipulating Date elements in Tableau. I've encountered the following error:

```
An error occurred while communicating with the Other Databases (ODBC) data source 'database (new.database) (__MarkLogic)'.

Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source.
ERROR: XDMP-CAST: (err:FORG0001) Invalid cast: () cast as xs:date;
Error while executing the query
SELECT SUM("database"."amount") AS "sum_amount_ok",
  SUM("database"."offered") AS "sum_offered_ok",
  "database"."type" AS "type"
FROM "new"."database" "database"
WHERE (CAST({fn TRUNCATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST("database"."date_of_permit" AS DATE)),0)} AS INTEGER) = 2014)
GROUP BY 3
```

Running this query (removing the {fn} tag) in qconsole results in the same casting error. How do I resolve this?

Thanks!

Update:
As grtjn commented, there is a null entry in my data that is causing this casting error.

Comment: `() cast as xs:date` sounds like you are trying to cast an empty value to a date. That doesn't work. Did you check your data for completeness?

Comment: You are correct. There's a row with a null data that's causing this error. Thanks @grtjn!